# I want to make 65 holes all around this piece in Open SCAD, but How to?

Tags: autocad, cad, openscad

I want to print a little device for a water pump which act like a sprinkler. I have seen one very simply made from a ball with holes. I want to make one very similar, but I don´t know how to make the holes. I need around 65 holes with 1mm diameter.

This is my code:

```
union()       {

difference() {resize(newsize=[60,90,20]) translate([0, 0,-9]) sphere(r=10);
resize(newsize=[58,85,19]) translate([0, 0,-9]) 

sphere(r=10);}


difference() {cylinder(70,12,12) ; cylinder(200, 11, 11, center = true);}
```

Comment: How should the holes be distributed on the sphere?

Answer (score 3):

You can reach a relatively easy and even distribution by using the Fibonacci Lattice, or, equally, a Golden Ratio spiral.
The theory behind this distribution (and others) is explained well in [this article](http://extremelearning.com.au/evenly-distributing-points-on-a-sphere/).

We use this to punch a number `N` of cylindrical holes into the sphere (before deforming it with `resize`).

```
GOLDENRATIO = 1.618;

resize([60,90,20]) {
  difference() {
    sphere(10);
    sphere(9);

    N=65; // number of points to distribue
    // height angle (given as multiple of PI) until which to distribute holes.
    max_height_angle = 0.8;
    for(i=[0:N]) {
      radius = 10 - 2;
      theta = 360*i / GOLDENRATIO;  // (0..N*360°) / 1.618
      phi = acos(1 - max_height_angle*i/N);
      // translate (theta, phi, r) to cartesian coords
      xi = cos(theta)*sin(phi) * radius;
      yi = sin(theta)*sin(phi) * radius;
      zi = cos(phi) * radius;
      translate([xi,yi,zi]) rotate([0,phi,theta]) cylinder(h=2, r=0.5, $fn=12);
    }
  }
}
```

The `phi` angle goes (for `max_height_angle==2.0`) from the bottom of the sphere to the top, while `theta` increases in steps of `360°/GOLDENRATIO`. This gives a nice even distribution of points over the sphere. However, since we only want to have points in the lower part of the sphere, we set `max_height_angle=` to 0.8, so points are distributed on the lower half of the sphere, minus the equator.

The angles `theta` and `phi`, together with `radius`, form a 3D polar coordinate system, which is translated into Cartesian coordinates `[xi, yi, zi]`.

The `rotate` orients the cylindrical holes on the sphere. You can leave this out and make the cylinders somewhat longer if you want the holes to be perpendicular to the ground.